# 2 Knight Checkmate

Tags: chess

Is it possible to have a two knights + king vs king checkmate if the king is very smart? I know that if the king goes to the corner, it is possible to checkmate, but is it possible to checkmate in any other way?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about creation or solving of puzzles.

Comment: Umm... It's kind of a puzzle.

Comment: I would, but I think that it could classify as "Real problems or questions that you have encountered"  Realistically, I think the issue is that it's lacking information, on why this question exists.

Comment: This would be better asked on chess.stackexchange.com.

Comment: In fact, [it has been](http://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/5281/checkmate-with-two-knights).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[No](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two_knights_endgame#Two_knights_cannot_force_checkmate), two knights cannot force a checkmate.